# How to use HttpServletRequest#getParts() in a servlet filter running on Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, file-upload, servlet-filters

I would like to upload a file in my JSF application. I am using a `Filter` and `HttpServletRequestWrapper` to access the upload file.

```
 public MultipartRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
    super(request);
    System.out.println("Created multipart wrapper....");
    try {
        System.out.println("Looping parts"+getParts().size());

        for (Part p : getParts()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Part name: %1$s, contentType : %2$s", p.getName(), p.getContentType()));
            for(String header : p.getHeaderNames()){
                System.out.println("Header name : " + header + ", value : " + p.getHeader(header));
            }
            byte[] b = new byte[(int) p.getSize()];
            p.getInputStream().read(b);
            params.put(p.getName(), new String[]{new String(b)});
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Logger.getLogger(MultipartRequestWrapper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ServletException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
        Logger.getLogger(MultipartRequestWrapper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

However, `getParts()` returns an empty collection. How can I enable `multipart/form-data` parsing in a servlet filter in Tomcat 7.0.8?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In order to get [`HttpServletRequest#getParts()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts%28%29) to work in a [`Filter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) in Tomcat, you need to set `allowCasualMultipartParsing="true"` in the webapp's [`<Context>`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) element in `Webapp/META-INF/context.xml` or `Tomcat/conf/server.xml`.

```xml
<Context ... allowCasualMultipartParsing="true">
```

Because as per the servlet 3.0 specification the [`HttpServletRequest#getParts()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts%28%29) should only be available inside a [`HttpServlet`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) with the [`@MultipartConfig`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html) annotation. See also the documentation of the [`<Context>`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) element:

> #### `allowCasualMultipartParsing`
>
> Set to `true` if Tomcat should automatically parse `multipart/form-data` request bodies when `HttpServletRequest.getPart*` or `HttpServletRequest.getParameter*` is called, even when the target servlet isn't marked with the `@MultipartConfig` annotation (See Servlet Specification 3.0, Section 3.2 for details). Note that any setting other than `false` causes Tomcat to behave in a way that is not technically spec-compliant. The default is `false`.

#### See also:

- [Tomcat 7 issue 49711](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49711)
- [Uploading files in Servlet 3.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-in-servlet-30.html)
- [Uploading files in JSF 2.0 and Servlet 3.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-with-jsf-20-and-servlet.html)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the following is definitely not right:

```
byte[] b = new byte[(int) p.getSize()];
p.getInputStream().read(b);
params.put(p.getName(), new String[]{new String(b)});
```

First, you are not respecting the character encoding specified by the client -if any. Second, this will fail for binary files.

Comment: I am using tomcat 7.0.33 I am using apache commons fileupload and I make change in Tomcat/conf/context.xml as above but it not work for me. Please help

Comment: @Mayank: This question/answer is not about Apache Commons FileUpload. It's about the new Servlet 3.0 builtin `multipart/form-data` parser. This Tomcat configuration setting has completely nothing to do with Apache Commons FileUpload. Your concrete problem is caused elsewhere. Just press `Ask Question` if you still stucks. In the meanwhile, this answer may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824

Comment: thank you for your quick reply but I am little bit confuse about my issue because multipart request cancelled automatically by tomcat. not even servelt init called. Any suggestions please?

Comment: There is a similar solution to enable upload by filter under Wildfly?

Answer (score 0):

Also try Multipart filter. worked for me.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.MultiPartFilter</filter-class>
</filter> 
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name> 
</filter-mapping>
```