# Primefaces FileUpload with PrettyFaces and JSF 2.2.3

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, prettyfaces

I'm having some problems with PrettyFaces on the pages I use `<p:fileupload>`.

When I disable the PrettyFaces filter on the page, everything works just fine. When I put it back, I can see the HTTP traffic on the webbrowser, but my fileupload handler is never fired.

This is some relevant part of the code.

Any help would be appreciated!

My .xhtml

```
<h:form id="formImportarSNs" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
<p:fieldset legend="Admin Panel">    
   <p:fileUpload value="#{adminPanelBean.file}" mode="simple"/>                            
   <p:commandButton ajax="false" actionListener="#{adminPanelBean.upload}"            value="confirm" />  

</p:fieldset>  
</h:form>
```

My backingBean

```
package br.sgrd.bean;  

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;  
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;  
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;  
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;  
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;  
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;  

import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;  

@ViewScoped  
@ManagedBean  
public class AdminPanelBean{  

    private UploadedFile file;  

    public void upload() {    
        if(arquivo != null) {    
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", file.getFileName() + "     is uploaded.");    
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);    
        }    
    } 

    // getters/setters/etc

}
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"  
    version="3.0">  
    <display-name>GRD</display-name>      

    <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet>  
    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>             
    <filter>  
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>  
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>  
    </filter>  
    <filter-mapping>        
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>  
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>  
    </filter-mapping>   



</web-app>
```

My pretty-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces  
                      http://ocpsoft.org/xml/ns/prettyfaces/rewrite-config-    prettyfaces.xsd">  

    <url-mapping id="admin_panel">  
        <pattern value="/admin_panel" />  
        <view-id value="/faces/xhtml/admin_panel.xhtml" />  
    </url-mapping>  

</pretty-config>
```

Edit: Cleaned up some code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've found the solution.

Create the `context.xml` in the META-INF folder and put this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context allowCasualMultipartParsing="true">
</Context>
```

You can remove the Fileupload Filter from `web.xml`

Where I found the solution: http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/docs/faq

And that's why you need to put it: [How to use HttpServletRequest#getParts() in a servlet filter running on Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047173/how-to-enable-multipart-form-data-in-tomcat-7-0-8-server/8050589#8050589)

If your problem is the size of the file, take a look at: [<p:fileUpload> limiting to 2 Mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256767/pfileupload-limiting-to-2-mb)

Comment: Does it work for file uploads above 2-3 MB file size ? In my case it works for small image uploads after adding your solution but not for larger file uploads.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256767/pfileupload-limiting-to-2-mb

Comment: Thanks.. it would better if you include this link in your answer to make it more complete,.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work very well. Works with upload small files. If the file is a few MB he can not invoke the method. I do not advise using Primefaces + prettyfaces.

If your case is upload small files can work. Remove the primefaces fileupload configuration of web.xml and create the context.xml file as mentioned above.

I did with '`rewrite-servlet-2.0.9.Final.jar`'. It worked perfectly with upload small files.

Answer (score -1):

Use in web.xml

```
<filter>  
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```