# <p:fileUpload> limiting to 2 Mb

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I'm having some issues with `fileUpload`. It's not firing the  `fileUploadListener` when the file is > 2 Mb.

The component:

```
<p:fileUpload id="upload" required="true"
fileUploadListener="#{myBean.handleFileUpload}"
fileLimit="1"
requiredMessage="A file is required"
fileLimitMessage="One file only"
invalidFileMessage="Invalid file"
cancelLabel="Cancel" label="Choose"
allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
```

Enviroment: JSF 2.2.3, Primefaces 4.0, Tomcat 7

Might it be some "filter" configuration problem?

@EDIT: More info. Same problem with `mode="simple"`.

Comment: Was this problem only from within the prettyfaces rewritten urls? In my case it worked fine but except with the pretty rewritten urls that showed this limitation !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomcat has a default maximum POST size of 2MB which is configurable in the [HTTP `<Connector>` configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) in its `/conf/server.xml`. Here's an extract from the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html):

> `maxPostSize`
>
> The maximum size in bytes of the POST which will be handled by the container FORM URL parameter parsing. The limit can be disabled by setting this attribute to a value less than or equal to 0. If not specified, this attribute is set to 2097152 (2 megabytes).

Thus, if you want to disable it, do so:

```
<Connector ... maxPostSize="-1">
```

*(`0` can also, but the `-1` is more self-documenting as to "allow every size")*

Comment: Could I somehow specify it within the `context.xml` file inside my application ?