# request.getparameter not working on multiple servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets

When the user fills the Sign up form(on page `Reg.jsp`) the data is successfully forwarded to the servlet(`Regi.java`) and when i use `<%=request.getParameter("username")%>` on one of my jsp pages(`Imgu.jsp`-which asks user to upload image) it works fine but when the same data is requested on another servlet(`imgup.java`) the value of parameter username is null.

I cannot understand why this happens i have tried creating a session but it did not work.

Comment: i hope you are clear on the concepts of request being `forward or Redirect`

Comment: how are redirecting from Regi.java to Imgu.jsp, forward/include/redirect ?

Comment: because `username` is not in the request scope anymore

Comment: in case u r using sendredirect() this won't work.
Since the response is sent only when you submit to other page or use request dispatcher, both of which send the response object along with.
Still if u want to achieve this, you may use request.setAttribute("",""); to set the value 
and request.getAttribute(""); to fetch the value..

Comment: Please give precise interactions between the servlets and JSP. As currently written it is *unclear*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**Regi.java**

```
  HttpSession session = request.getSession();
  session.setAttribute("username", request.getParameter("username"));
```

**Imgu.jsp**

```
<form>
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="${username}"/>
</form>
```

***OR***

**Regi.java**

```
  HttpSession session = request.getSession();
  session.setAttribute("username", request.getParameter("username"));
```

**imgup.java**

```
  String username = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("username");
```

Answer (score 0):

As the documentatioin says request.getParameter()

> Returns the value of a request parameter as a String, or null if the
>   parameter does not exist. Request parameters are extra information
>   sent with the request. For HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in
>   the query string or posted form data.

So it is related to **one** request. Unless you provide parameter in query string or posted form in the request the other servlet it wont be there.

For data that should be shared a cross requests use the session scope as Arvind suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem you are having has to do with the fact that you are dealing with multi-part requests (because you are uploading an image).  Tomcat 7 has a feature that deals with this:

[How to use HttpServletRequest#getParts() in a servlet filter running on Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047173/how-to-enable-multipart-form-data-in-tomcat-7-0-8-server)

Otherwise, you may want to use a multipart library to extract the parameters.