# How do I forward my http request

Tags: java, httprequest, struts

In my application I am using Struts, I have introduced a filter in web.xml to check any malicious character available in request or not before it reaches to corresponding action or .do . 
If any malicious character available I need to redirect to error page and if not, I want to allow the request to corresponding action or .do. How can I forward the request to original request after filter check?

```
   <filter>
      <filter-name>MaliciousFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.MaliciousFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
```

Comment: Which Struts are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Just invoke

```
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

and you will pass request back down the filter chain. If you don't have more filters the original action will be called.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Let me try with it.

Comment: It is working but I have some other problem. When I try to getParts. It is coming empty for multipart/form-data. I can get getParts only in HttpServletRequest. But I am not able to access HttpServletRequest inside doFilter. Even though I type cast from servletRequest to HttpServletRequest . I am getting empty value for getParts. Can you please help me how to resolve?

(final Part part : ((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest).getParts())

Comment: is there a way to access HttpServletRequest inside doFilter without type casting from ServletRequest. Because if type caste, I will get getParts as empty value.

Comment: It isn't a casting problem...What Server are you using? Maybe you find this useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047173/how-to-enable-multipart-form-data-in-tomcat-7-0-8-server

Comment: I am using Tomcat server. When I invoke doFilter method,
doFilter (ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,FilterChain filterChain) I can't use getParts() in doFilter(). getParts() is available in HttpServletRequest. Even though I type cast to HttpServletRequest, I get null value.
Is there any way to access HttpServletRequest inside doFilter without type caste from servletRequest? or how Can I directly access HttpServletRequest inside doFilter without passing it into the method?
Error Snippet
for(final Part part : ((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest).getParts())

Comment: Did you set allowCasualMultipartParsing="true" in the webapp as @BalusC suggest in his post?

Comment: I have tried but I facing issue while accessing it. When I put allowCasualMultipartParsing="true" in context.xml. It checks multi part for every request. So if it content type null or text/html, I am getting exceptions. Is there way to enable if request is only multipart/form-data